# Migrate WebMatrix project to VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, webmatrix

So I recently asked a question about how I could use a database with ASP.NET, the answer I received suggested I use WebMatrix. Well, I can say that I definitely like the simplicity of WebMatrix. With Visual Studio 2010 I couldn't figure out how to create a database for my site, and with WebMatrix it was very, very easy. But along the journey of working on my project, WebMatrix crashed when I started typing in one of my files. So I re-opened it, and opened the same file, typed in the same code, and it crashed again, at the same time as before.

I used Visual Studios Just In Time Debugger to see what the problem was, here is the exception I get when the application crashes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A Task's exception(s) were not observed
either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property.
As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.
```

I'm not asking you to tell me why it crashed, but I thought I would include it just in case anyone has something to say about it.

Anyways, it has become apparent to me that WebMatrix isn't very stable. At first I thought it was my computer, but the fact I was able to completely replicate the crash told me otherwise. So, now that WebMatrix is crashing every time I try to edit this one file, I would like to use another IDE.

I wanna go back home to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate :(
But the reason I left it in the first place is because I couldn't figure out how to use the database, but I would much rather tough it out, figure out how to use my websites database with Visual Studio 2010, and get some stability back!

Okay, wrapping it up here: **(How) can I pick up the development of my website with VS2010 when I first created the project with WebMatrix? Will the development be the same (C# files go in `App_Code` folder, pages are `.cshtml` files with Razor syntax, not `.aspx` files)? And WebMatrix database management was a breeze, how is database management done with VS2010 (I've messed around in the Server Explorer looking for a way to do this but couldn't figure it out)?**

Regarding that last part about database management, that part of the question doesn't HAVE to be answered, if I can successfully use my site with VS2010 then that's good enough for me and I will figure the rest out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Open Web Site option within Visual Studio and browse to the folder containing your web site. Or, open the site in WebMatrix and click the Launch button that has a Visual Studio icon on it when you are in the Files workspace. That will open you site in Visual Studio.

If you want to work with a SQL CE 4.0 database in Visual Studio 2010, you will need to install SP1.